# How to pass variables to a class

Tags: c++

I have been working on this code for quite some time now and I had posted it before but then after fixing that problem another problem arose so I created a new post with the name of this problem. Ok the problem is that I am obviously not passing the variables to the Administrator class the right way. I have tried two ways which is all my book shows and both have given me an error that says error C2512: 'SalariedEmployee' : no appropriate default constructor available". I have tried

```
  //Lynette Wilkins
//Week 12

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class SalariedEmployee
{
private:
    double wageRate;
    int hours;
protected:
    string name;
    string ssn;
    double netPay;
    string department;

public:
    SalariedEmployee(string n, string s, double np, double w, int h, string d);
     ~SalariedEmployee() {cout<<endl;}
     string Getname();  //returns name
     string Getssn();   // returns social security number
     double GetnetPay(); //returns netPay
     string Getdepartment(); // returns department
     double GetwageRate(); //returns wage rate
     int Gethours(); //returns hours
     void Setname(string); //sets name
     void Setssn(string); //sets ssn
     void SetnetPay(double); //sets net pay
     void Setdepartment(string); //sets department
     void SetwageRate(double); //sets wage rate
     void Sethours(int); //sets hours

};

SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee(string n, string s, double np, double w, int h, string d) : name(n),
      ssn(s),
      netPay(np),
      wageRate(w),
      hours(h),
      department(d)
{}


string SalariedEmployee::Getname()
{
    return name;
}

string SalariedEmployee::Getssn()
{
    return ssn;
}

double SalariedEmployee::GetnetPay()
{
    return netPay;
}

double SalariedEmployee::GetwageRate()
{
    return wageRate;
}

int SalariedEmployee::Gethours()
{
    return hours;
}
void SalariedEmployee::Setname(string n)
{
    name = n;

}

void SalariedEmployee::Setssn(string s)
{
    ssn = s;
}

void SalariedEmployee::SetnetPay(double np)
{
    netPay = np;
}

void SalariedEmployee::Setdepartment(string d)
{
    department = d;
}


void SalariedEmployee::SetwageRate(double w)
{
    wageRate = w;
}

void SalariedEmployee::Sethours(int h)
{
    hours = h;
}


class Administrator : public SalariedEmployee
{
protected:
    string title;
    string responsi;
    string super;
    double salary;
public:
    Administrator(string t, string r, string s, double sa);
     ~Administrator();
    string Gettitle();
    string Getresponsi();
    string Getsuper();
    double Getsalary();
    void Settitle(string);
    void Setresponsi(string);
    void Setsuper(string);
    void Setsalary(double);
    void print();
};


Administrator::Administrator(string t, string r, string s, double sa) :  title(t), responsi(r), super(s), salary(sa)
{
}

Administrator::~Administrator()
{
    cout<<endl;
}

string Administrator::Gettitle()
{
    return title;
}

string Administrator::Getresponsi()
{
    return responsi;
}

string Administrator::Getsuper()
{
    return super;
}

double Administrator::Getsalary()
{
    return salary;
}
void Administrator::Settitle(string ti)
{
    title = ti;
}
void Administrator::Setresponsi(string re)
{
    responsi = re;
}


void Administrator::Setsuper(string su)
{
    super=su;
}

void Administrator::Setsalary(double sa)
{
    salary= sa;
}

void Administrator::print( )
  {

    cout << "\n_______________________________________________\n";

    cout << "Pay to the order of " << name<< endl;
    cout << "The sum of " << netPay << " Dollars\n";
    cout << "_________________________________________________\n";
    cout <<endl<<endl;
    cout << "Employee Number: " << ssn << endl;
    cout << "Salaried Employee. Regular Pay: " 
       << salary << endl; 
    cout << "_________________________________________________\n";
  }





int main()
{


    string name;
    string soc;
    double net = 0;
    double wage = 0;
    int hrs = 0;
    string dept;
    string admtitle;
    string resp;
    string sup;
    double sal = 0;
    int response = 0;

    string date = "January 12, 2013";


    cout<<setprecision(2)
    <<setiosflags(ios::fixed)
    <<setiosflags(ios::showpoint);

    SalariedEmployee emp1(name, soc,net, wage, hrs, dept);
    Administrator adm1(admtitle, resp, sup, sal);


while(response != 4){

    cout<<"Employee and Administrator Salary Program "<<endl;
    cout<<"(You will have to enter data first before you do anything else)"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter Employee Data,  Enter 1"<<endl;
    cout<<"Change data,   Enter 2"<<endl;
    cout<<"Print Check,   Enter 3"<<endl;
    cout<<"End Program, Enter 4"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Please make your selection"<<endl;



cin>> response;

    switch (response)


    {
    case 1:
        cout <<"The employee's data will be entered here: "<<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"Enter the employees name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, name);

        cout<<"Enter the employees social security number: ";
         cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, soc);

        cout<<"Enter the employees net pay: ";
        cin>>net;

        cout<<"Enter the employees wage rate: ";
        cin>>wage;

        cout<<"Enter the number of hours the employer worked: ";
        cin>>hrs;

        cout<<"Enter the employees title: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,admtitle);

        cout<<"Enter the employees area responsibility: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, resp);

        cout<<"Enter the employees salary: ";
        cin>>sal;



        cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;


        break;




    case 2:

        cout<<"Please change the data you entered previously here. " <<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"Enter the employees name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, name);

        cout<<"Enter the employees social security number: ";
         cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, soc);

        cout<<"Enter the employees net pay: ";
        cin>>net;

        cout<<"Enter the employees wage rate: ";
        cin>>wage;

        cout<<"Enter the number of hours the employer worked: ";
        cin>>hrs;

        cout<<"Enter the employees title: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,admtitle);

        cout<<"Enter the employees area responsibility: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, resp);

        cout<<"Enter the employees salary: ";
        cin>>sal;



        cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
break;



    case 3:

        cout <<"Information Printed"<<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"_____________________________"<<date<<endl;
        &Administrator::print;



        break;


    default:

        cout<<endl<<endl
            <<"Invalid Selection! Try Again"<<endl;
        exit(1);

}
}





    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Administrator(string t, string r, string s, double sa);` will attempt to call the default constructor of the base class if you don't specify another. (a default constructor is one that can be called without any arguments)

The base class doesn't have a default constructor, ergo the error.

To call another constructor of the base class:

```
Administrator::Administrator(string t, string r, string s, double sa) :  
SalariedEmployee(<args>), //base constructor call
title(t), responsi(r), super(s), salary(sa) //members
{
}
```

Comment: OK!! So where you have (<args>) what arguments are being passed here?

Comment: @CarlaBridgesWilkins that's part of the logic. I pointed out the error, can't help you with the logic. Think about it. An Administrator is a SalariedEmployee, ergo has all its properties. What's the Administrator's name when you create it as `Administrator adm1(admtitle, resp, sup, sal);`? (my guess is you have to add more parameters to `Administrator`'s constructor to accomodate those of the base class'.

Comment: OK I have tried nothing is working.  I feel like pulling my hair out right now!!!

Comment: @CarlaBridgesWilkins what if you change your constructor to `Administrator::Administrator(string t, string r, string s, double sa, string bn, string bs, double bnp, double bw, int bh, string bd) : SalariedEmployee(bn, bs, bnp, bw, bh, bd), title(t), responsi(r), super(s), salary(sa)` and pass all the arguments you need.

Comment: Ok I will try this and see how this works.  Thanks for the help Luchian